# Add Custom Button to Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

I've got a Custom Object called `Opportunity__c` and a Custom Button (onClick JavaScript) called `Convert_to_Vacancy`. Finally, I've got a Visualforce Page called `Opportunity` that overrides the record's View.

I'm trying to make use of the button and include it in the `Opportunity` Visualforce Page, but I'm not having a lot of luck doing something I thought would be simple.

I've tried:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!$Action.Opportunity__c.Convert_to_Vacancy}" value="Convert to Vacancy" />
```

But this won't work, the response is a load of JSON my IDE can't parse.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!Convert_to_Vacancy}" value="Convert to Vacancy" />
```

But this won't work (as expected) because of this error:

> Unknown method 'Opportunity__cStandardController.Convert_to_Vacancy()

And

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity__c.Convert_to_Vacancy)}" value="Convert to Vacancy" />
```

Which redirects me to a Page that doesn't exist, regardless of whether I add `Opportunity__c.Id` as a parameter in `URLFOR`.

I'm lost here, how do I include an onClick JavaScript button on a Visualforce Page that overrides the standard view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you move the logic to a **`Visualforce Button`**, it is much more straightforward to reuse, thanks to the `URLFOR` syntax.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Page.MyButtonPage, null, [Id=Opportunity__c.Id])}" />
```

---

If you must stick with Javascript, it's slightly less straightforward. As far as I know, any Javascript code you place directly in the button configuration is going to be impossible for you to reuse. You need to put it somewhere you can get it! **`Static Resources`** to the rescue.

You will likely need to tweak your style to use the same `Javascript` in your custom button and on a `Visualforce Page`, but you can put the code somewhere both can use it. The structure would be something like:

**Static Resource**

```
(function (w) {
    "use strict";
    w.myButtonController = w.myButtonController || {};
    w.myButtonController.doStuff = function () {
        // logic here
    });
    Object.freeze(w.myButtonController);
}(window));
```

**Custom Button**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/ModalButton')}
(function (w) {
    "use strict";
    w.myButtonController.doStuff();
}(window));
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:commandButton styleClass="myButton" value="Do Stuff!" />
...
<script>
    (function (w, D) {
        "use strict";
        D.getElementsByClassName("myButton").forEach(function (element) {
            element.addEventListener("click", w.myButtonController.doStuff);
        });
    }(window, document);
</script>
```

Comment: Damn, I was hoping I was missing something simple here with "calling" the button to the page. Luckilly the button just calls a helper class anyway, so this shouldn't be too problematic. Thanks for clearing this up Adrian.